# Select rows within a certain range

Tags: mysql

I've attempted to search but not sure I'm getting the keywords correct for this.

I want to select rows in desc order that aren't the last 5 rows but the 5 before that!

So if I had 140 rows, I want rows 131-135.

The following ets me 136-140.

```
SELECT id, title, content, date FROM tbl_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

How could I change the limit value to achieve 131-135?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the two parameter limit:

```
SELECT id, title, content, date FROM tbl_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5, 5
```

This will give you the first 5 rows after row 5(so rows 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) which is the 5 rows before the last 5 like you want.

Edit: Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9113a/1

It should return id's 4-8 as there are 12 records here.

Comment: Glad I could help, figured that would let you mess around the query to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Limit can take 2 parameters, offset (which is zero based) and quantity, so you can use this:

```
SELECT id, title, content, date FROM tbl_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10, 5
```

To get 5 rows, starting at row 10

For you case, you can do

```
SELECT id, title, content, date FROM tbl_news ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 129, 5
```

Comment: The figures I quoted were just to help understand the question. Are rows will grow and I always want the 5 previous to the last 5. Will your first query do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, title, content, date FROM tbl_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5,5;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT id, title, content, date FROM tbl_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10,5
```

Comment: yes, the first parameter is the offset the second is the amount to take. So it would offset by 10 then take 5

Comment: Except the OP wanted an offset by 5, which you dont explain in your post what the values represent.

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for you?

```
select top 5 id
from tbl_news
where id not in
(
    select top 5 id
    from tbl_news
    order by id desc
)
order by id desc
```

Comment: You might be talking about other database systems. `top` is not recognized in MySql.

Comment: Was going to say the same! Never come across top using mysql before?

Comment: That's true...I had assumed MySql had top function

Comment: All database systems are very different.  mssql for example doesnt have the `LIMIT` command. You need to know what system you are working on before providing an answer because of all of these differences in key words.